# Detect if the url is redirecting before iframing it

Tags: php, iframe, redirect

i am building an app and i am stuck at some point, i am having an iframe that it's source is dynamically determined according to :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','off');
$file = $_GET['file'];
$url = ('remotedomain. com/' .$file);
?>
```

now here is the iframe:

```
<iframe id="embed" src="<? echo $url; ?>"></iframe>
```

the point i am stuck at is sometime the url(that's the iframe source) is redirecting back to home page, i want to detect this redirect and if it will happen then the source of the iframe should be certain url for example mysite .com/page1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every one who discussed this with me i have managed to do and here is the answer so if anyone need it:

> ```
> $url = (remote site .com/' .$file);
> $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
> $handle = curl_init($url);
> curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
> curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
> $response = curl_exec($handle);
> $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
> if($httpCode == 302) {
> $final_url = 'mysite .com/page1.php';
> }
>  else {
>  $final_url = $url;
>  }
> ```

Comment: @OIS check how i did it

Answer (score 0):

Use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and the option [CURLOPT_HEADER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). It's something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/"); //your url
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (preg_match('#HTTP.{4} 30[34]#m', $result)) {
    if (preg_match('#\vLocation: (.*)\v#m', $result, $matches)) {
        echo "Found redirect: ", $matches[1], "\n";
    }
}
```

You can instead use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle), it will [follow redirects](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#redirects).

```
$response = $client->get('http://github.com');
echo $response->getStatusCode();
// 200
echo $response->getEffectiveUrl();
// 'https://github.com/'
```

getEffectiveUrl(); will here print where it redirected to.

Something like this:

```
function getFinalUrl($url) //in your library 
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get($url);
    if (in_array($response->getStatusCode(), [303, 304], true)) {
        $url = $response->getEffectiveUrl();
    }
    return $url;
}
```

And iframe:

```
<iframe id="embed" src="<?=getFinalUrl($url);?>"></iframe>
```

Comment: `function get_url($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
    }` i dont know how then i procced may you help me!

Comment: @sherifhalim Try guzzle instead. curl might be initimidating.

Comment: after getEffectiveUrl(); i get where it redirect, how i can set it if redirect to example.com set the iframe source to mysite .com/page1.html

Comment: @sherifhalim I don't understand that question.

Comment: i prefer to use CURL but i tried your code and its not working for me

Comment: what is the library i have to add for the code to work?

Comment: @sherifhalim just Guzzle. Put that code in your library.

Comment: i am sorry but this not worked throw 2 errors  Undefined variable: client in and Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

Answer (score -1):

You can lookup the current URL of an iframe with the following javascript:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

You can compare this url to that of the homepage you want to avoid. If they match redirect them to your alternate URL

Comment: i want do this before i iframe the url